# What's the difference between getRepository with or without getManager?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I used code:

```
    $userRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository(User::class);
```

but today while analyzing some tutorial I found out that code without getManager does the same

```
    $userRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(User::class);
```

So, what's the difference? The devil's in the detail so I'm curious.

Thanks,
L

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same thing if you only have one connection :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database

```
->getManager()
```

allows you to choose the connection.

Personally, I always use the full format, by convention ;)

Comment: That's right. I found old post from stack about getEntityManager and there were examples. I posted that in answer for next people who go here from Google

Answer (score 1):

After research I found old post from stack about similar case:

- [getEntityManager() and getDoctrine() in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316006/getentitymanager-and-getdoctrine-in-symfony2)

So:

1. In past, there was getEntityManager() - deprecated since 2.1
2. getEntityManager = getManager in my case
3. If you want to use one Entity you can skip getManager

Comment: If you really want to understand the devil's details, consider taking a peek at the code itself.  Might be surprised.